# How do we use both 'request.headers' and 'requestpathParam' in Serenity BDD API testing?

Tags: java, api, cucumber-java, serenity-bdd

This code doesn't work

```
sam.attemptsTo(
    Get.resource("/byName/{search_text}").with(request -> request.headers(header))
                        .with(request -> request.pathParam("search_text",search_item))
    );
```

But below code works fine

```
sam.attemptsTo(
    Get.resource("/byName/Apple").with(request -> request.headers(header))
);
```

The response status code is 400 in case of using both the 'request.header' and 'request.pathParam' but response in case of sending only then header I get 200 Ok status response code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server was returning a 500 error whenever there was a non matching /unavailable data in the back-end. So there was nothing wrong with code syntax or semantic. The parameter was the issue.